# How to create a List which of type Activity in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
List<Activity> allowedActivites = new ArrayList<>();
allowedActivites.add(SplashActivity.class);
allowedActivites.add(SubscriptionActivity.class);
```

How to create a List which is of type activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items that you're trying to add to your list are classes. If you want a list of classes that extend `Activity`, the type is `List<Class<? extends Activity>>`.

So you can do

```
List<Class<? extends Activity>> allowedActivites = new ArrayList<>();
allowedActivites.add(SplashActivity.class);
allowedActivites.add(SubscriptionActivity.class);
```

as long as those are subclasses of `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you very much